# Newton-Raphson for reciprocal square root

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, approximation

I have a question about using Newton-Raphson to refine a guess of the reciprocal square root function. The reciprocal square root of $a$ is the number $x$ which satisfies the following equation:

$$x^{-2} = a$$

So we are looking for the root of the following equation:

$$x^{-2} - a = 0$$

Applying the Newton-Raphson method then leads to the following:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)} = x_n - {x_n^{-2} - a \over -2x_n^{-3}} = x_n(1.5 - 0.5ax_n^2)$$

Before looking up the above standard solution, I tried to come up with my own equation:

$$x^2 = {1 \over a}$$

In this case, we are looking for the root of a different equation:

$$x^2 - {1 \over a} = 0$$

And the Newton-Raphson method gives us:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)} = x_n - {x_n^2 - {1 \over a} \over 2x_n} = 0.5(x_n + {1 \over ax_n})$$

Is there anything wrong with this alternative approach, and why would I choose one over the other?

Comment: You would choose the first if you implement it on a computer because multiplication is faster than division.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Fischer's Comment points out, your alternative requires a division with each iteration.  Historically your alternative was the "standard" approach to applying Newton's method to finding square roots, being older by centuries than Newton's calculus!  See for example the [Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

The slowness of division vs. multiplication on early mainframes motivated the division-free Newton iteration for solving $x^{-2} = a$, as noted in the Question:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n(1.5 - 0.5 * a * x_n^2) $$

Despite the general acceleration of floating point operations on microprocessors, division [continues to be significantly slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication) than multiplication on popular platforms.  It follows that keeping the count of division operations low is still a valid design consideration.

Note that if $\sqrt{a}$ is really needed, rather than $1/\sqrt{a}$, we can get it with one additional multiplication:

$$ \sqrt{a} = a \cdot (1/\sqrt{a}) $$